# Uncaught TypeError: _firebase_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.db.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I think I know why this isn't working (the way Firebase had its syntax changed in v9 or something?), but I'm not sure what changes. I've checked the documentation, but I'm still confused.

```
import { db } from './firebase.js';  

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([

  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
    });
  }, []);
```

The error I get is this:
Uncaught TypeError: *firebase_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3*_.db.collection is not a function
or something similar to this except for my .map().

This is my guess of what I should write:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "posts"))
    setPosts(onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      console.log("Data", querySnapshot.docs.map(d => doc.data()))
    }))
  }, []);
```

But I can't seem to get this to work either.

firebase.js in case its needed:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);

export { db };
```

(edit)
Solution:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "posts"))
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      console.log("Data", querySnapshot.docs.map(d => d.data()))
    })
  }, []);
```

Comment: Don't just guess what the new APIs should be - there is [documentation for listening to realtime queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).  Did you follow it?  If you have a specific error or behavior using the v9 API that isn't what you expect, your post should explain that.

Comment: In the 2nd code snippet, `setPosts(querySnapshot.docs.map(d => doc.data()))` should be within `onSnapshot()` but you have `onSnapshot()` in `setPosts()`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input @DougStevenson and @Dharmaraj! It seems that my issue was exactly what Dharamaraj said.